# SQL - variable is null after breaking from loop

Tags: sql, sql-server

When  breaking from a while loop, the @XSQL_Query (B) variable is being set back to NULL. When calling the @XSQL_Query (A) variable within the loop, it returns the string.

Why is this, and how can I use the @XSQL_Query outside of the loop?

```
BEGIN

DECLARE @StartPeriod DATE;
DECLARE @EndPeriod DATE;
DECLARE @NoOfMonths INT;
DECLARE @ListOfMonths TABLE (MonthName Varchar(15), MonthNo int);
DECLARE @MonthName Varchar(15);
DECLARE @SQL_Query nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @XSQL_Query nvarchar(max);

SET @StartPeriod = '2021-01-01';
SET @EndPeriod = '2021-02-28';

SET @NoOfMonths = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(DATENAME(MONTH, PlannedDate))) from DT_PLANNED_TRANSACTION WHERE PlannedDate BETWEEN @StartPeriod AND @EndPeriod);

SET @XSQL_Query = 'SELECT ';

INSERT @ListOfMonths
SELECT DISTINCT DATENAME(MONTH, PlannedDate), MONTH(PlannedDate) 
from DT_PLANNED_TRANSACTION WHERE PlannedDate BETWEEN @StartPeriod AND @EndPeriod;

WHILE (1=1)
BEGIN
SET @MonthName = '';
SET @MonthName = (SELECT TOP 1 (MonthName) FROM @ListOfMonths ORDER BY MonthNo);

SET @SQL_Query = 'MAX (CASE WHEN t.[MONTH] = ''' + @MonthName + ''' then t.DateValue end) ''' + @MonthName + ' Date'',
MAX (CASE WHEN t.[MONTH] = ''' + @MonthName + ''' then t.Transactions end) ''' + @MonthName + ' Transactions'',
MAX (CASE WHEN t.[MONTH] = ''' + @MonthName + ''' then t.balance end) ''' + @MonthName + ' Balance'',';

SET @XSQL_Query = @XSQL_Query + @SQL_Query;

IF @MonthName IS NULL
        BREAK;

SELECT @XSQL_Query as A; <-- ** Returns the concatenate string on each select **

DELETE @ListOfMonths WHERE MonthName = @MonthName;

END;

SELECT @XSQL_Query as B; <-- ** Returns NULL **

END;
```

[image]

Comment: You break on monthname becoming null. By that point you've already concatenated it with a bunch of other strings. Null propagation results in the whole query being null too. Basically I think you just want to break out earlier.

Comment: To clarify: Breaking out of the loop before concatenating to `@XSql_Query` will fix that part of the problem. You could also say `while exists (select 1 from @ListOfMonths)`. Adding null to a string is not the same as appending an empty string.

Comment: Have you considered using `STRING_AGG` or `FOR XML` to generate your SQL in half the code?

Comment: Please don't use images for code, data or errors. Use formatted text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The reason this is happening:**

The check for `IF @MonthName IS NULL` only happens after the concatenation with the existing SQL `SET @XSQL_Query = @XSQL_Query + @SQL_Query;`, and when you concatenate `NULL` with anything by using `+`, you get `NULL`.

We could solve this by switching to `CONCAT` which doesn't have that problem, or by moving the `IF` higher up.

**But there is a much better method to do this.** Just create the whole dynamic pivot in one `select` by using grouped concatenation

```sql
DECLARE @StartPeriod DATE = '2021-01-01';
DECLARE @EndPeriod DATE = '2021-02-28';

DECLARE @XSQL_Query nvarchar(max) =
'SELECT 
' +
(
    SELECT STRING_AGG('
   MAX (CASE WHEN t.[MONTH] = ' + QUOTENAME(MonthName, '''') + ' then t.DateValue end) ' + QUOTENAME(@MonthName + ' Date') + ',
   MAX (CASE WHEN t.[MONTH] = ' + QUOTENAME(MonthName, '''') + ' then t.Transactions end) ' + QUOTENAME(@MonthName + ' Transactions') + ',
   MAX (CASE WHEN t.[MONTH] = ' + QUOTENAME(MonthName, '''') + ' then t.balance end) ' + QUOTENAME(@MonthName + ' Balance')

    , ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY MonthNo)
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT DATENAME(MONTH, PlannedDate) MonthName, MONTH(PlannedDate) MonthNo
        from DT_PLANNED_TRANSACTION
        WHERE PlannedDate BETWEEN @StartPeriod AND @EndPeriod
    ) ListOfMonths
)
+ '
from DT_PLANNED_TRANSACTION
WHERE PlannedDate BETWEEN @StartPeriod AND @EndPeriod;
';

SELECT @XSQL_Query;

EXEC sp_executesql 
    @XSQL_Query,
    N'@StartPeriod date, @EndPeriod date',
    @StartPeriod = @StartPeriod, @EndPeriod = @EndPeriod;
```

If you are on SQL2016 or earlier, you will need to use the `FOR XML PATH('')` method instead of `STRING_AGG`, there are many examples of this online.